# Ext JS 4: Get TreeStore node by internalId

Tags: extjs, tree, extjs4, store

Is it possible to get a node by its internalId? I tried:

**Store**

```
Ext.define('myStore', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
  storeId: 'treestore',
  root: {
    text: 'root',
    children: [{
      text: 'leaf1',
      id: 'leaf1',
      children: [{
        text: 'child1',
        id: 'child1',
        leaf: true
      },{
        text: 'child2',
        id: 'child2',
        leaf: true
      }]
    },{
      text: 'leaf2',
      id: 'leaf2',
      leaf: true
    },{
      text: 'leaf3',
      id: 'leaf3',
      leaf: true
    }]
  },
  proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
      type: 'json'
    }
  }
});
```

**Tree**

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
  id: 'myTree',
  rootVisible: false,
  store: Ext.create('myStore'),
  width: 300,
  height: 500,
  renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

**Adding and getting node**

```
Ext.getCmp('myTree').getRootNode().appendChild({id: 'test', text: 'test', leaf: true});  // this test node takes on the internalId 'ext-record-2'
Ext.getCmp('myTree').store.getNodeById('ext-record-2');  // returns undefined
Ext.getCmp('myTree').getRootNode().findChild('id', 'ext-record-2', true);  // returns null
Ext.getCmp('myTree').getRootNode().findChild('internalId', 'ext-record-2', true);  // I was just trying things at this point.
```

I realize this probably isn't possible, so I'll explain what I'm trying to do... I'm trying to change the id of a node, so when I use `getNodeById`, I can use the new id that I made. The idea is, if I changed the id, I could find it in the tree and it would be unique because I only allow for adding unique id's... but the id wouldn't change. I then thought using the 'ext-record' id would make sure I return a unique id, but then I couldn't figure that out, haha.

Here's some code showing what I'd like to do.

```
var node = Ext.getCmp('myTree').store.getNodeById('test');  // returns my test node
node.beginEdit();
node.set('id', 'blah');
node.endEdit();
node.commit(false);
alert(Ext.getCmp('myTree').store.getNodeById('blah'));  // returns undefined
alert(Ext.getCmp('myTree').store.getNodeById('test'));  // still returns my test node
```

I tried using the tree's sync method, but that didn't do anything. I'm just wondering how I can update the node's id, so when I use `getNodeById`, I can use the new id. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please post some code how you are creating your tree store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things:

1. Try to debug it step by step. I.e. debug what you're getting after Ext.getCmp().store and Ext.getCmp().getTreeRoot(). Check if the node has any children in array.
2. What exactly is beginEdit/endEdit? NodeInterface doesn't have these methods.
3. Why are you trying to change Id? I'm just curious - it's very unusual task for my taste.

Comment: 1.  I've debugged it, and everything is kosher.

Comment: 2.  [beginEdit](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-beginEdit), [endEdit](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-endEdit), and [commit](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-commit) are all part of Model, which NodeInterface inherits from.  They're supposed to ensure no other process will update the store.

Comment: 3.  I'd like to give the user the ability to change the text of a node, and when they change the text of the node, I want the id to change with it.

Comment: 1. How kosher is it? You do see childrens inside the root node?

Comment: 2. According to http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface - it doesn't inherit from the Model.

Comment: 1.  Yep, everything is as it should be.

Comment: 2.  You're right that the hierarchy doesn't show it, but doesn't this `"This class is used as a set of methods that are applied to the prototype of a Model to decorate it with a Node API. This means that models used in conjunction with a tree will have all of the tree related methods available on the model."` mean it does inherit from Model?  Either way, try it yourself... load up my code, get the node, and type "beginEdit," it's available for use.

Comment: 3.  Why not the ID's?  I no longer want that ID associated to the old text... maybe you can elaborate a better approach?

Comment: Id is id. It's the identity of existing record. Don't need to change that if some other property changed

Comment: So let's say I have a button that lets the user add a node... in the code, I just append a dummy node with 'test' as the ID and text.  If the user keeps appending children, there are multiple nodes with the 'test' ID and text, which means, they're not unique.  If the user edits the node they added, I can change the ID, but then when I search the tree for the new ID with `getNodeById`, it doesn't work (like I stated above)... which is why I'm trying to use internalId because it's more unique!

Comment: I think I fixed it.  When I was appending a child, I was adding in the ID 'test' for that child, but by leaving it out, Ext JS uses its internalId ('ext-record-2') as the node's ID.  I ended up doing `Ext.getCmp('myTree').store.getNodeById(record.internalId)`, where record is the record of the node I'm looking for.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var node = Ext.getCmp('myTree').queryById('ext-record-2');
```

Answer (score 1):

tree.getNodeById(...) find only node that expanded. Please reference [getNodeById does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634946/getnodebyid-does-not-work)